# Image augmentation for multiple input giving infinite loop?

Tags: python-2.7, keras

I am trying to implement image augmentation for multiple input, however my implementation seem to be going into infinite loop. Posted the code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
data_gen_args = dict(      
    horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=True)  # randomly flip images


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)


datagen.fit(X_train,seed=1)
datagen.fit(X1_train,seed=1)
datagen.fit(X2_train,seed=1)
datagen.fit(X3_train,seed=1)
datagen.fit(X4_train,seed=1)


multi1=datagen.flow(X_train, seed=1)
multi2=datagen.flow(X1_train, seed=1)
multi3=datagen.flow(X2_train, seed=1)
multi4=datagen.flow(X3_train, seed=1)
multi5=datagen.flow(X4_train, seed=1)


multigen=zip(multi1,multi2,multi3,multi4,multi5)




model.fit_generator(multigen,y_train,samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0],
                            batch_size=8,
                            nb_epoch=1,                                    
                            validation_split=0.2,
                            shuffle=True,
                            callbacks=[xyz])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `zip` tries to iterate through all outputs of `multi*` and returns them as a list of tuples. But since `multi*` are infinite iterators, `zip` will just keep iterate through `multi*` and never return.

The solution here is to use `itertools.izip` which is an iterator version of `zip`.

Just import itertools

```
import itertools as it
```

And then zip the generators together

```
multigen = it.izip(multi1, multi2, multi3, multi4, multi5)
```

For more information about  `itertools`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html